# Simulate focus() while mouse is away

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, focus

I'm currently developing a chrome extension and in order to make it work I often need the script to focus input fields. I know this can be achieved by using something like

```
document.getElementById('field').focus();
```

and it perfectly work. However it needs you to mantain the tab active and focused, otherwise the focus() event won't trigger. To explain it better, just consider this code and run it on google's homepage:

```
document.getElementById('lst-ib').focus();
```

You'll see that, of course, the cursor goes in the search field. However, if you put a setTimeout, launch the script and then go away from the tab with google, you can see that the focus() event hasn't been fired because the tab wasn't active. So my question is: is it possible to fire a focus() event or even to simulate it while mouse isn't on the page you want to run the code in?
I haven't found anything about this, so it might be a silly question and I apologise for it, but I can't really imagine if there's a way to achieve my goal. Thanks!

---

I didn't put any specific code just because I wasn't looking for a precise answer but for a general one, that I hoped might be more useful to other people. To be precise, my extension would run on this HTML (I can't put here the exact page since it requires a login for internal people):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="1000000000000000" id="num" placeholder="Insert a number" aria-required="true">
<button id="submit">Go!</button>
```

that takes in input a number and checks its properties, e.g. if it's prime. This is the code I'm using.
Content script:

```
var x;//global
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ask: "number"}, function(response)    {
x=response.number;
});

document.getElementById('num').value=x;//insert number
document.getElementById('num').focus();//focus field
document.getElementById('submit').click();//click submit button
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({do : "increment"});//communicates with bgpage asking to increment x
```

where x is a variable from background script that increments by one at each iteration. 
These are those parts in **bgpage**:

```
var x=0;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
if (request.do == 'increment'){//this is the increment of x
x+=1;}
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)    {
if (request.ask == 'number'){//and here it's sending the value of x
     sendResponse({number: x});
}
});
```

Finally, the only important thing in my **manifest** is that I have the following permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
    ],
```

If I set the value **without** focusing the field, it acts like I didn't enter anything in the field since I didn't click on it. Instead if I insert the value manually it goes without problems. So, with the focus() instruction it works, but if the tab becomes inactive it stops working, as if the field is empty. So what I wanted to know is how to make the focus() work without having the mouse on the page, since the extension should run for about 1-2 hours and it would be a pain in the neck to keep the tab active for all that time.

Now I think the question should be clear enough, there's nothing more I can write about this specific problem, since the remaining part of the code is working and the code I posted should be enough to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Bit off topic, but why wouldn't you use something like `document.querySelectorAll("input").focus()`, instead?

Comment: @Caelan. I think it's the same... I used the getElById just to explain the problem, which is only related to the focus() instruction

Comment: Chrome throttles background tab timers to 1 per second.

Comment: @wOxxOm so does this means that as the tab becomes inactive all the setTimeout timers are reduced to 1 sec? That might be a problem... However, even without using timers, the focus() event isn't dispatched, so I think it's not related to timer instructions...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Based on the [example as answer that was provided by Joffutt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41616384/3773011), Chrome can certainly focus inputs while the tab is not visible. Thus, we need a [mcve] from you that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @Makyen I hope it's ok now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could be going wrong with your code but this example will focus on the first text box upon the page losing focus, and then 5 seconds later will focus on the second text box. For this example I have only done this when the page loses focus.

You can also set it up so that you will create repeating focus events while the page is not active and then remove those repeating events once the page gains focus again.

```js
var grabFocus = function(id) {
  var d = new Date();
  //Added print outs to show the focus location and times
  console.log('focusing on ' + id);
  console.log(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var hidden, visibilityState, visibilityChange;

  if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "hidden", visibilityChange = "visibilitychange", visibilityState = "visibilityState";
  } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden", visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange", visibilityState = "msVisibilityState";
  }

  var document_hidden = document[hidden];

  document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
    if (document_hidden != document[hidden]) {
      if (document[hidden]) {
        //Document is hidden
        grabFocus('test');
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          grabFocus('delay')
        }, 5000);
      } else {
        // Document shown
      }

      document_hidden = document[hidden];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" />
<input id="delay" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However my purpose is not to focus the field as the mouse goes out. I mean, the fields need to get focused in precise moments, as the content script run a specific line, and not everytime the mouse goes out. I would just like to be able to make the fields continue to focus while the tab isn't active, but not AS the tab becomes inactive.